# IntelliJ CE + Maven package without the IDE

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I tried to search "Build jar without IDE" without any success, if anyone have any pointers, I would be happy to RTFM.

I haven't touched Java in about 5 years now, and everything seems <strike>a little</strike> very different.

I have an IntelliJ Java application, standard Java application, with some maven dependencies. I can go to Build > build artifacts, and it would generate a jar for me in which I can run the application by `java -jar out.jar`

The version of the IDE: IntelliJ Community Edition 2016.1

The content of the `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

However, how can I build this application with the commandline, as if I was pressing "build artifact" from the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build artifacts [configured through the project structure settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-artifacts.html) are stored in IntelliJ's project files, and are not automatically available through the command line.  To build the artifact through Maven, you should manually translate your IntelliJ artifact configuration to a [Maven Shade Plugin configuration that creates an executable jar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html).  Assuming that your existing artifact configuration simply contains everything in your project, that would look like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.example.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Add that snippet before your `</project>` tag in your `pom.xml`, then run `mvn package` on the command line, and Maven will generate an `app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` file in your `target` directory which can be run with `java -jar`.  If you want to generate the same artifact from within IntelliJ, you can do that by accessing the `package` lifecycle phase from the [Maven Projects Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/maven-projects-tool-window.html).